# Input Value is returning as undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to retrieve the value of the input box and print it to the div. It keeps coming back as undefined and I don't know why. Here is my code:

```
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <button type="button" id="btn">Click me</button>
    <div class="square"></div>
    
    <script>
        const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
        let divEl = document.querySelector(".square");
        
        btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            
            let nameEl = document.querySelector("#name").val;
            
            console.log(nameEl);
            
        });
        
        
    </script>


</body>
```

Comment: `.val` is a jQuery thing. Use `.value`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your
`let nameEl = document.querySelector("#name").val` to
`let nameEl = document.querySelector("#name").value`

Everything than should work fine.